# Using str_replace on the_content and the_excerpt, but not working on archive index pages

Tags: the-content

I am using code like this to replace a string in my posts.

```
function replace_text($text) {
$text = str_replace('look-for-this-string', 'replace-with-this-string', $text);
$text = str_replace('look-for-that-string', 'replace-with-that-string', $text);
return $text;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text');
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'replace_text');
```

This is working great, except on my archive index pages. On these pages, the text is not being replaced. What am I missing?

Comment: it seems this function is being add to the content filter and also to the excerpt filter, should this not be add also to the filter for the archive index pages

Comment: I agree with @tiago - in most themes, nothing more should be required (assuming your code is in or consistently loaded by a main plugin file or `functions.php`). It may be possible that your theme is acquiring excerpts in a non-standard manner which does not trigger the filter, however - you'd need to inspect the archive templates to be sure.